# Finding the longest substring in a string

Tags: python, strings

I am writing Python code to find the longest substring in a string which is an alphabetical order. I tried to minimize the number of loops to a single for loop.

Any improvements would be appreciated. Any details about the complexity of this algorithm would also be welcome, because I don't know Big-O notation all too well.

```
substr = '';
final_substr = '';

for index, char in enumerate(s):
    if index < len(s) - 1:
        #print('Comparing %s and %s'% (char, s[index+1]));
        if ord(char) <= ord(s[index + 1]):
            substr += char;
            print(substr);
        else:
            substr += char;
            if len(final_substr) < len(substr):
                final_substr = substr;
            substr = '';

print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: '+final_substr);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Double bug

One bug is that if the longest non-decreasing substring is at the end,
it will be ignored.

A second bug is that the fix more complicated than adding this at the end:

```
if len(final_substr) < len(substr):
    final_substr = substr
```

This is not enough, because the last character will not have been appended yet.

The fix is not very pretty:

```
for index, char in enumerate(s):
    if index < len(s) - 1:
        if ord(char) <= ord(s[index + 1]):
            substr += char
        else:
            substr += char
            if len(final_substr) < len(substr):
                final_substr = substr
            substr = ''
    else:
        if index > 0 and s[index - 1] < char:
            substr += char
        if len(final_substr) < len(substr):
            final_substr = substr
```

#### The forced `enumerate`

`enumerate` is great.
In many situations it gives you index and element pairs of iterables,
which is truly awesome.
But in this case it's just not a good fit:

> ```
> for index, char in enumerate(s):
>     if index < len(s) - 1:
> ```

For each character there is a check on length twice:
once in the mechanism of `enumerate` itself,
and one more time inside the loop.

I suggest to rewrite with either `for pos in range(len(s) - 1)` or `for pos in range(1, len(s))`.

Actually, even better, as [@kyrill](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/134576/kyrill) suggested,
you could do `for i, c in enumerate(s[:-1]):`.

#### Don't repeat yourself

`substr += char` appears in both branches of this conditional,
it can be easily lifted out:

> ```
> if ord(char) <= ord(s[index + 1]):
>     substr += char
> else:
>     substr += char
>     if len(final_substr) < len(substr):
>         final_substr = substr
>     substr = ''
> ```

#### Compare characters directly

There's no need for `ord`. You can compare characters directly, for example:

```
if char > s[index + 1]:
```

Comment: Ad `enumerate` – you probably meant `range(len(s) - 1)`. A better alternative would be `for i, c in enumerate(s[:-1]):`.

Comment: @kyrill thanks, yeah, that's what I meant, and great tip! (added to my answer)

Answer (score 11):

- The algorithm has linear (\$O(n)\$) time complexity, which is good; you can't do better. It also has a linear space complexity, which is not so good; only a constant space is really required. Notice that you don't need to build `substr` (`substr` consumes memory!). It suffices to keep track of the start and end indices.
- The test for `index < len(s) - 1` is un-pythonic. [Don't ask permission, ask forgiveness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python).
- The intention to

  > minimize the number of loops

  is dubious. Does it improve run time? Most likely, no (if you doubt, measure). Does it improve readability? Most likely, no. Consider the pseudocode

  ```
    while start_index < string_length:
        length = scan_ordered_substring(string, start_index)
        do_business_logic
        start_index += length
  ```
- I don't think that

  ```
      print(substr);
  ```

  was intended.

Comment: "has linear time complexity" - why is that? Doesn't string concatenation have O(n+m), making the whole loop O(n^2)

Comment: You're right, print(substr) was not intended. I left it in there by accident. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You mentioned the algorithm complexity and the peace of code you wrote  shows you love good coding ... I just wish you mentioned that `if` problem

Answer (score 6):

#### Don't bother with `ord`

Python already provide syntactic sugar for comparing characters in codepoint order, so `ord(char) <= ord(s[index + 1])` can be shortened to `char <= s[index+1]`

#### Don't bother with the index

You only use `index` as a mean to look at the next character in `s`, you can dispense with it if you do

```
substr = s[0]
for char in s[1:]:
    if substr[-1] <= char:
        substr += char
    else:
        # Do your things
```

#### Don't use a string as an accumulator

Making `substr` a string is (probably) not the most efficient way to do it, as strings are immutable and you are constantly modifying it, better to make it a list of chars and join it only when needed

```
final_substr = []
substr = [s[0]]

for char in s[1:]:
    if substr[-1] <= char:
        substr.append(char)
    else:
        if len(substr) > len(final_substr):
            final_substr = substr
        substr = [char]

if len(substr) > len(final_substr):
    final_substr = substr
final_substr = ''.join(final_substr)
```

#### Extra fanciness

in the code above, the string slicing `s[1:]` copies `s`, which might be an issue if you have to apply this procedure to a lot of very long strings. You can avoid that copy by using an iterator over `s`, changing the lines above to

```
s_iter = iter(s)
final_substr = []
substr = [next(s_iter)]

for char in s_iter:
   # Nothing changes after this line
```

Or you could be more pedestrian and iterate over `range(len(s))`.

In the same vein, if you expect to have to deal with long substrings, you could transform everything to keep track of only the bounds of `substr`

```
final_bounds = [0, 1]
substr_bounds = [0, 1]
for i in range(1, len(s)):
    if s[i-1] <= s[i]:
        substr_bounds[1] += 1
    else:
        if final_bounds[1] - final_bounds[0] < substr_bounds[1] - substr_bounds[0]:
            final_bounds = substr
        substr_bounds = (i, i)

if final_bounds[1] - final_bounds[0] < substr_bounds[1] - substr_bounds[0]:
    final_bounds = substr
final_substr = s[final_bounds[0]:final_bounds[1]]
```

This version should be the most efficient of all memory-wise. I do find it disgraceful, though.

Answer (score 4):

[Python does **not** require semicolons as a terminator](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Python-not-require-semicolons-at-the-end-of-statements). You should refrain from using them.

Comment: The only reason I always make sure to use semicolons is because I've heard its a good habit to maintain across programming languages, and is something I picked up from JavaScript. Is using a semicolon not considered pythonic?

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ this is a perfectly legit answer. Please read https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/short-answers-and-code-only-answers

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ yes it says that. And then? I don't see the connection between that and this answer. Are you sure you didn't quote out of context? I think that post overall means that this answer is fine, do you disagree?

Comment: @ZaidHumayun unnecessary semicolons are decidedly unpythonic. And the advice to use semicolons across programming languages is a very bad advice that should not be followed.

Comment: Yes, I disagree.  I can not write *remove semicolon* or *remove space* as an answer. Such things could be written either as a comment or mentioned  in an elaborated answer. I think all SE websites look for good quality posts. @janos

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Is it my interpretation of the linked meta post that you disagree with, or is it the meta post itself that you disagree with? We certainly look for good quality posts. Care to come chat about this stuff in the [site's main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)?